# How to append several imageDataObjects or converting an unstructeredGrid to an imageData

Tags: vtk

is it possible to append several imageDataObjects keeping there
transform informations?
vtkimageappend appends imageDataObjects along an axis only.

vtkappendpolydata keeps the transform informations of several
polydataobjects build with the vtktransformpolydatafilter.

I want to append several imagedataobjects and finally get the
scalarcomponentasdouble of the new imagedata.

I also tried to append the imageDataObjects with the "vtkAppendFilter", but the output is an unstructeredGrid. Is it possible to convert this grid to an imageDataObject?

best regards
Chris

Answer (score 0):

The `vtkImageAppend` class has a method `AddInputData (vtkDataObject *)` and the class `vtkImageData` inherits from `vtkDataSet` which inherits from `vtkDataObject`. So you can use you `vtkImageData` objects in the algorithm vtkImageAppend.

The vtkImageAppend has a method `vtkImageData* GetOutput ()` and the output of type vtkImageData has the method you want :

`virtual double GetScalarComponentAsDouble (int x, int y, int z, int component);`

The [vtkAppendFilter](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAppendFilter.html#details) is use only for get an vtkUnstructuredGrid object, but vtkUnstructuredGrid inherits from vtkDataSet but **not** from vtkImageData

> vtkAppendFilter : appends one or more datasets together into a single unstructured grid

Be sure the [vtkImageAppend](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageAppend.html#details) has the behavior you need :

> Collects data from multiple inputs into one image.
>
> vtkImageAppend takes the components from multiple inputs and merges
>   them into one output. The output images are append along the
>   "AppendAxis". Except for the append axis, all inputs must have the
>   same extent. All inputs must have the same number of scalar
>   components. A future extension might be to pad or clip inputs to have
>   the same extent. The output has the same origin and spacing as the
>   first input. The origin and spacing of all other inputs are ignored.
>   All inputs must have the same scalar type.

Answer (score 0):

VTKimageAppend appends objets along an axis, but i do not want that. Every ImageDataObject inherits transformationdata about their position in space. I want too keep these informations.
vtkappendfilter keeps these informations for each object, but the output is an unstructeredgrid, not an imagedata.